# OOPs whats happening here in this assignment

Tags: c#, oop

I came across these lines of code

```
ClassA classAObject;
//some lines of code that hydrate 'classAObject'
DerivedFromClassA derivedObject = classAObject as DerivedFromClassA;
```

whats going on, on the last line? Is it assigning to derivedObject only those values that are in common between derivedObject and classAObject ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it's broadly equivalent to:

```
DerivedFromClassA derivedObject = null;
if (classAObject is DerivedFromClassA)
{
    derivedObject = (DerivedFromClassA) classAObject;
}
```

In other words, the result will *either* be a null reference, *or* a reference to the same object, but statically typed to be of the derived type.

Answer (score 3):

No, it's accessing the same object, but you now have access to the parts of that object from type `DerivedFromClassA`. There is only one object.

Additionally, if classAObject is not an instance of `DerivedFromClassA` or a type derived from it, then derivedObject will be null, as there's no valid cast.